# Android dialogs and listviews show text inline

Tags: android, android-listview, android-dialog

Suddenly, all alertdialogs and listviews in my app became to show text inline.
This problem appears on Android 2.x.
On android 4.x everything is fine.
I use actionbarsherlock.
I don't use custom layouts for dialogs.
I don't know where there is problem :-(

AlertDialog bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R988Z.jpg
ListView bug: https://i.stack.imgur.com/agl7r.jpg

Create a dialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage(R.string.is_check)
    .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            go2check();
        }})
    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
 });

 AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
 alert.show();
```

This problem is with alertdialogs, listviews, progressbars, buttons etc.. on android 2.x....

Comment: Please add some snippet of your code

Comment: I added a code. But I have this problem with all aletdialogs, progressbars and listviews.

Comment: What do you mean by `all alertdialogs and listviews in my app became to show text inline`? Don't see what is wrong in the images...

Comment: Text in any components (linearlayouts, buttons, dialogs, etc) doesn't transfer at new line. It shows how one line. Text which doesn't placed in that line hides for right edge.

Comment: I dropped in AndroidManifest line:

    android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo"

And all was well.
Thank to all.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped in AndroidManifest line:

```
android:theme="@style/android:Theme.Holo"
```

And all was well.
Thank to all.